# "!q" and "wq!" failed to quit vim

Tags: vim

I tried to quit vim

```
"/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts"
"/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts" E212: Can't open file for writing
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

When I press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, it returns to edit mode. I tried

```
!q

Press ENTER or type command to continue
[No write since last change]
/bin/bash: q: command not found

shell returned 127

Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

I press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, it returns to the previous editor mode again.

How can I quit vim in this situation?

Comment: because you cannot replace `q!` with `!q`

Answer (score 2):

If you want save changes `:wq!`, but if something wrong and you want quit anyway (ignore changes) - `:q!`

Often you can start edit file with no permissions to save it. You can make many changes and then understood, you can't save it. In this case i recommend **save as** it:

```
:w tmp_filename
```

then exit vim and replace old file with **tmp_filename**.